# How to handle if it is not filtered

Tags: angular, filter, router

Is there a way to handle if a router event is not filtered when using it?

I want to process it when it is not filtered, but I do not know what to do.

```
this.router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart)
      .pairwise()
      .subscribe((event: any[]) => {
            // If...
      }
);
            // I want to Else { }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I think you are forgetting the pipe method (or using an older version of rxjs):

```
this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart),
        pairwise()
      )
      .subscribe((event: any[]) => {
            // If {}

            // I want to Else { }
});
```

Comment: Please explain a little more.
If it does not belong to pipe, where do I handle it?

Comment: Tell the truth, I don't know what the pipe is related to. I want to divide the case of being router.events.filter and the case of not filtering.

Comment: For example, if I refresh in a browser, it will not be filtered.

Comment: pipe is a method of rxjs that allows you to perform operations on observables, before you emit them. In this case, you are getting an Observable of router events...

You want to pipe this response, by the operator filter (as provided in my answer), and therefore, it will only allow to pass those that meet the crtieria of being instances of Navigation Start. you are trying to apply a filter to the events observable, and since that's not an operation of an observable, it will fail